# bhyve RAM usage doesn't match configuration

Tags: memory, virtualization, hypervisor

I am currently using the bhyve hypervisor on my FreeNAS system but with only 16G of RAM, running virtual machines is more or less a stretch for the system.

I have only *one* VM running Debian right now.

This is its configuration:

```
Getting debianguest iohyve properties...
bargs             -A_-H_-P
boot              1
con               nmdm1
cpu               2
description       Wed Feb  8 18:16:58 CET 2017
install           no
loader            grub-bhyve
name              debianguest
os                debian
persist           1
ram               3G
size              50G
tap               tap0
template          NO
vnc               NO
vnc_h             600
vnc_ip            127.0.0.1
vnc_tablet        NO
vnc_w             800
vnc_wait          NO
```

The important bit is `ram=3G` where it specifies the amount of virtual RAM available to the VM.

Now here comes my issue: This virtual machine is using **way more** RAM on the host than what I allocated for it.

Output from `ps aux -O %mem`:

```
root       28769  9.1 32.2 7519108 5357236  -  S     8:28PM  18:21.80 bhyve: ioh-debia
```

Output from `htop`:

```
PID   USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
28769 root       20   0 7342M 5233M S  7.0 32.2 18:30.40 bhyve: ioh-debianguest
```

Output from `free -h`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2.9G        1.1G         90M         71M        1.8G        1.6G
```

It's currently using 5.2GB of RAM when only 3 are configured.

It also has about 90M of free space, 1.6GB usable for applications and **0K** in swap, leading me to the assumption that either the hypervisor (bhyve) or the kernel is somehow leaking memory.

EDIT:

While I understand that allocating more memory to aid performance is a good thing to do (and I expect this), forcing the process itself being swapped or even worse, killed by the OOM Killer, makes me question how aggressive this aim for performance is.

Is there any way to find out why it is using more RAM on the host than allocated and is there a way to reduce the amount of RAM used on the host?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. But you have no reason to suspect that any memory is  being leaked. You asked for 3G inside the VM, and that's what the VM shows.

Comment: Yes, but why is it using 5.2G on the host. This is basically the question I am asking.

Comment: Because it can. Why shouldn't it? It's not like you can save that RAM for later.

Comment: So I ask for 3G of RAM and using 2.2G extra for nothing makes sense? The issue is, that ZFS is *very* sensitive to low memory situations and is kept in buffer (meaning it can be discarded when more memory is needed), this can lead to occasional hangs (about 5 minutes long so that *nothing* works and I fear it being locked in that state, the VM even reports the CPU being locked).

Comment: Ahh, so you asked the wrong question! Your question is why the memory isn't being released when needed, not why it's not being used when it's freely available. Clearly, you should prefer that the 2.2G extra be used if that's possible, rather than wasted.

Comment: Well, I don't even know the correct question, it's more like: It is using more memory than I configured it and instead of releasing it, it just allocates more, I had times when it used nearly 9G, but only 3G are available to the VM (used RAM was about 1.5G + buffers). There is no reason for it to use *that* much more memory when it is not even available to the VM.

Comment: There is a reason -- the only options available are using it or wasting it. So it prefers to use it, since wasting it provides no benefit whatsoever and using it might avoid some I/O. It is available to the VM in the form of improved performance through avoidance of I/O delays among other things. The RAM setting you've configured is the amount the guest sees as always guaranteed available. The hypervisor can use more to improve performance and will if the alternative is wasting that RAM. But if you're seeing performance problems, that's a problem, and you should tell/ask us about it.

Comment: I'm going to monitor it more closely, I understand reaching for higher performance but forcing so much memory usage that it needs to be swapped out doesn't seem like a good strategy here.

Comment: For example, say the VM writes 1GB of data to the virtual disk. The hypervisor could make the VM wait until that data is written to the physical disk. But since it has 1GB of RAM that would otherwise be wasted, it *should* use that RAM to hold the writes until they can be flushed to the host OS. And, yes, you're right, if it needed to be swapped out, that would be a problem. But that's not what you're reporting and not what you asked about. If it's freely available, it should be used. Not otherwise, of course. But you're not reporting any performance problem or swapping.

Comment: No, no real performance issue, just crashing the entire VM by the OOM Killer because I'm out of swapping space (happened twice today).

Comment: As I said, you didn't ask the right question. If you have an actual problem, the first thing you should do is describe it!

Comment: I disagree. The question is good: Why does it use so much memory? A hypervisor should either rely on host caching or just not cache at all. The guest OS will take care of that. But there's really no need to discuss that here and neither is there any need to speculate about what happens. What's needed are bhyve-specific facts.

Comment: @DanielB I don't think he's interested in *why* it uses so much memory. But if so, the answer is because it is free to do so and it can help performance. I gave a specific example above, buffering writes.